# All users getting "error creating /tmp//tmux-1003 (Permission denied)" when using tmux

Tags: permissions, tmux, tmp

tmux used to work, but i forgot exactly what I did on the server to cause all users to not being to use tmux. I'm getting the errors for 2 different users:

`error creating /tmp//tmux-1003 (Permission denied)`

and

`error creating /tmp//tmux-1006 (Permission denied)`

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe permissions for `/tmp` are incorrect?

Comment: currently showing: drwx------  17 root root      69632 Sep 15 20:39 tmp/

Comment: Those are not the default normal permissions for `/tmp` but `drwxrwxrwt` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change permissions for `/tmp` to `1777`. (*the leading `1` will set the sticky bit ie. `t` in `drwxrwxrwt` so that only creators of files can delete them*) Run this:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Then see if it works.